# How to making timetable layout with lecture data in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'am making school timetable using flutter
First, the whole code looks like this.

```
Widget weekTable(String week, List<LectureSlot> lectureSlots) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Table(
        border: TableBorder(
          right: BorderSide(
            color: week == "FR" ? Colors.transparent : Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
        ),
        children: [
          TableRow(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            ),
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 30.0,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    week,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          for (int i = 0; i <= latestEnd; i++)
            TableRow(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(
                            width: 0.50,
                            color: i % 6 == 0
                                ? Colors.grey.shade300
                                : Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          bottom: const BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    ...lectureSlots.map((slot) {
                      if (i >= slot.start[0] && i < slot.end[0]) {
                        return Positioned.fill(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              int currentNumber = slot.number;

                              setState(() {
                                weekLists.forEach((day, slots) {
                                  slots.removeWhere(
                                      (slot) => slot.number == currentNumber);
                                });
                                updateTimeTableEnd();
                                _saveWeekLists();
                              });
                            },
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Text('${slot.code}'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const SizedBox.shrink();
                      }
                    }).toList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is a widget that I made, and I made a timetable table using this.

```
child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              weekTable("MO", weekLists["MO"] ?? []),
                              weekTable("TU", weekLists["TU"] ?? []),
                              weekTable("WE", weekLists["WE"] ?? []),
                              weekTable("TH", weekLists["TH"] ?? []),
                              weekTable("FR", weekLists["FR"] ?? []),
                            ],
                          ),
```

My current situation, the situation I want to make, is the same as this picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJpCW.png)

What I don't know is this part of the second table row.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= latestEnd; i++)
            TableRow(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        border: Border(
                          top: BorderSide(
                            width: 0.50,
                            color: i % 6 == 0
                                ? Colors.grey.shade300
                                : Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                          bottom: const BorderSide(
                            width: 0,
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    ...lectureSlots.map((slot) {
                      if (i >= slot.start[0] && i < slot.end[0]) {
                        return Positioned.fill(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {},
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // Text('${slot.code}'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const SizedBox.shrink();
                      }
                    }).toList(),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Even if I put what I want to print out in the text widget, it keeps overlapping, probably because of 'for().'
Like the picture above.

Do you have any good ideas?

I'm making a timetable, where rows are generated for each time slot, and lecture data is provided in a similar format. Given that rows correspond to time slots, I'm finding it challenging to come up with an alternative solution. I'd like to display lectures within the colored cells corresponding to their respective time slots. How can I achieve this?

Since each day of the week has different lectures at various time slots, I want to insert the lecture information into sections that satisfy the conditions within the ...lectureSlots.map((slot) part of the code.

Comment: Have you tried with flutter data tables? Data tables might help you with the use case.